# How to properly deal with JWT in headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm trying to set up JWT in my project (NodeJs Express for the backend, and Javascript in frontend).

So in my backend, I send my token like this when the user logs in :

```
[...]
     return res.send({ token, id: userId })
[...]
```

And in my frontend, I set the Bearer token in my header like this :

```
const data = {
        email,
        password
    }

    await instance.post('/signin', data)
        .then((res) => {
                instance.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`
                window.location = './account.html'
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

My questions are :

- Did I do it correctly ?
- When I'm redirected to the `account.html` page, how do I retrieve the token that was set while the log in was made ?

Comment: Often you would encode the user id within the JWT itself, not needed and not recommended to expose the user ID when sending the token. Consider using a middleware in Express to check the token (in a httpOnly cookie) on every incoming request instead of handling it on a route to route basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to `instance.defaults.headers.common['authorization']` then **subsequent** requests made via **Ajax** using whatever library (I'm guessing Axios) that is **from that page** will include the `authorization` header.

Assigning a new value to `window.location` will trigger navigation and discard the `instance` object (with the assigned header value).

(As a rule of thumb, if you are going to assign a new value to `window.location` after making an Ajax request then you should probably replace the Ajax request with a regular form submission).

---

You could assign the data to somewhere where you can read it in the `account.html` page (such as local storage).

That won't be available to the server for the request for `account.html` itself though.

You could assign the data to a cookie. Then it would be available for the request for `account.html`, but in a cookie and not an authorisation header.

---

Note that using JWTs in authorization headers is something generally done in Single Page Applications and not traditional multi-page websites.

Comment: Ok... That's why. I'm not in SPA. Thank you very much ! Is localStorage safe to store JWT ?

Comment: I would recommend storing the token as a secure httpOnly cookie and not in a regular cookie  or in localStorage. The two latter are much less safe, accessible to javascript.